# Simple way to use knn classification only using knnsearch (MATLAB)?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, statistics, nearest-neighbor, knn

I have a vector, x, with 2 columns (column 1 is feature 1 and column 2 is feature 2), and with each row representing one data point. I also have another vector, let's call it c, which contains class labels for each data point (1 or 2), there are only 2 classes. Is there a simple way to build a K-NN classifier ONLY using knnsearch? I've tried for almost two full days now and I can't get it to work. I know which points of my data are the training, validation, and testing sets. I'm then supposed to look at the number of points being misclassified, and see how this changes as k is increased. Does anyone have ANY advice? I'd take anything I can get at this point. Even just a general outline.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been better if you added your code and specified which part of your code doesn't work. In general advice of how knnsearch works,

```
K = 1 % constant. 'K'th nearest neighbor
x = rand(10, 2) % 10 data with length 2 feature
c = rand(2, 2) % class data point, 2 classes with length 2 feature
outputClass = knnsearch(c, x, 'K', K) % knn-classifies x in c class points
```

outputs class of each point x.

```
outputClass =

     2
     2
     1
     2
     2
     2
     1
     2
     2
     1
```

That is, for each point in x, it returns the index of the closest point in c in Euclidean distance.

If you want to see how many of them are misclassified, you can use

```
sum(outputClass ~= expectedClass)
```

However, if you only have 2 classes, increasing K will be meaningless. KNN returns K classes that are close to the datapoint. If there are only 2 classes, KNN of K=2 will have exact same amount of information as KNN with K=1. Usually, you use KNN classification to classify a point to numerous classes, to find k closest classes.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but shouldn't c be your expected class? Or at least that's how I thought of it originally.

Comment: I don't think this is actually a classifier though, correct? If used this on training data, could I test on validation etc?

Comment: I see. You want to find the center of knn with training data labeled with c. You cannot use knn only to achieve this.

Comment: I would do this instead: Train data with kmeans (find center of each labels) -> Test data with knn (search point close to trained centers)

Comment: Are you saying I should find the mean of my results after using knnsearch, and then classify based on the distance from a point to that mean?

Comment: Training: find mean of train data with label 1 and mean of train data with label 2 Testing: search for k nearest neighbors of label 1 and label 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61616/discussion-between-junyoung-gwak-and-john-alberto).